# Neo4j Cypher result as Map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I would like to return a Cypher result as a Java Map.

I am able to return the result as a Map in Neo4j Browser like this:

```sql
MATCH (camera:Camera)-[:BELONGS_TO_IPU]->(ipu:Ipu)
WHERE ID(ipu) = 23
RETURN { id: camera.cameraSid,  camera: camera }
```

That results in:

```
{
  "id": 1001,
  "camera": {
    "name": "1001",
    "cameraSid": 1001,
    "ipuRecordId": 0,
    "uniqueIdentifier": "10011001"
  }
}
{
  "id": 1,
  "camera": {
    "name": "1",
    "cameraSid": 1,
    "ipuRecordId": 0,
    "uniqueIdentifier": "11"
  }
}
```

In the Java side, I am using Spring Data Neo4j and I am trying to fetch the Cameras like this:

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Query(" MATCH (camera:Camera)-[:BELONGS_TO_IPU]->(ipu:Ipu) " +
        "WHERE ID(ipu) = {0} " +
        "RETURN { id: camera.cameraSid,  camera: camera }")
Map<Long, Camera> findCamerasMapByIpu(Ipu ipu);
```

But what I get is this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected at most 1
```

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do? Or I will have to fetch all the Cameras and then create the Map by myself?

Comment: It's been a long time since I used Cypher, but your query _appears_ to return _an array of objects of {id, camera}_; Spring doesn't have any obvious way to convert that from `List` to `Map`.

Comment: The Cypher query would return a list of results, with each result being a separate map with two entries (where the two keys are `id` and `camera`).

Comment: @InverseFalcon so there is no way to return just a single map with their respective key-value, right?

Comment: You can do this, but it requires more advanced map creation/manipulation capabilities than is available in just Cypher. [Map functions in APOC Procedures](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/data-structures/map-functions/) will do the trick, `apoc.map.fromPairs()`, after you've done a `collect([camera.Sid, camera])`

Comment: @InverseFalcon  thanks, I'll give that a try